# Python equivalent to the Tcl's "string match"

Tags: python, string, tcl, matching, glob

I am looking for Python equivalent to the Tcl's [string match](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) operation. Specifically, I would like to handle correctly the special sequences (*, ?, and [chars]).

For example, given three Python strings:

```
expected = 'Foo? Bar* Tar'
actual1 = 'Foo2 Barfluff Tar'
actual2 = 'Foo Bar Tar'
```

the match operation `match(expected,actual1)` should return true, but `match(expected,actual2)` should return false.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are looking for regular expressions (module `re`).

Comment: @DYZ: Actually, for glob-like pattern matching, `fnmatch` is more appropriate. It's actually implemented using `re` under the hood (with caching so repeated use of the same glob pattern doesn't require reconverting/recompiling the equivalent regex over and over), but it works with shell wildcard patterns directly, no need to rewrite them into regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [the `fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html). While `re` provides full powered regular expressions, `fnmatch` performs the limited, shell-style globbing wildcard matching you're looking for.

For a case sensitive match, it's as simple as:

```
>>> fnmatch.fnmatchcase(actual1, expected)
True
>>> fnmatch.fnmatchcase(actual2, expected)
False
```

If you want to follow the operating system's case sensitivity rules (that is, insensitive on Windows, sensitive on most other operating systems), you'd use plain `fnmatch.fnmatch` to invoke automatic case normalization.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out fnmatch.fnmatchcase. That's exactly what I was looking for.